# "submit" button and open in new window doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

I use plugin Events Manager. If someone register on an event, click button 'submit' - and I'd like to open confirmation of register in a new window.
I did this:

```
`function my_em_booking_redirect(){
 ?>
jQuery(document).bind('em_booking_success', function() {
        window.open ('http://my domain')
});
<?php
}

 add_action('em_gateway_js', 'my_em_booking_redirect');`
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: what u r getting then????

Comment: Did you try to transparently call JavaScript in PHP?

Comment: I tried also `window.open = ('http://mydomain')`

Comment: thanks l2aelba, I tried both but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Paste somewhere in your `functions.php`

```
function my_em_booking_redirect(){ ?>
   jQuery(document).bind('em_booking_success',function() {
      window.open('http://domain.com');
   });
<?php }
add_action('em_gateway_js', 'my_em_booking_redirect');
```

or try

`window.open('http://domain.com');`

to

`window.location.href = 'http://domain.com';`

(redirect)